# Attach NGINX Configurations files with Persistence Volume on AWS EKS

Tags: nginx, kubernetes-pod, amazon-eks, kubernetes-pvc

I'am try attach my NGINX configurations files (config, ssl certificates, and others) to my NGINX POD on AWS EKS (Elastic Kubernetes Service). Reading about this i'am using Persistence Volume and Persistence Volume Claim as demonstrated on follow tutorial (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/).

My scenario is: i need to attach the configurations files localizated on `/mnt/data` into NGINX POD.

**Persistent Volume:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: task-pv-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

**Persistent Volume Claim:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: task-pv-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 3Gi
```

**NGINX POD:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: task-pv-claim
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: task-pv-storage
```

After running the Persistent Volume, Persistent Volume Claim and NGINX POD and access the running NGINX POD with `/bin/bash` the data that is located on my cluster at `/mnt/data` should be inside the `/usr/share/nginx/html` folder, correct? But when I access NGINX pod in the `/usr/share/nginx/html` folder my `/mnt/data` files are not there.

I'm new to development and maybe I'm missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: did you sovle this issue, if yes please answer here, I face the same problem but didn't get answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're creating a pod with nginx image the configuration created by the image will overwrite the existing files in the pod and which will also be reflected in the `/mnt/data` path also.

You've to move your config files to usr/share/nginx/html after pod creation by using commands in pod.yml file. You can map `/mnt/data` with tmp folder and use after creation commands to move files to `usr/share/nginx/html` so everytime you create a new pod your config file will generate in desired path also

Comment: I undestand you answer, but then the tutorial i went through above doesn't make sense, correct? because i have i that files located on /mnt/data has been inserted on /usr/share/nginx/html on POD.